# Curl POST to external domain

Tags: php, curl

I`m trying to create a script sending information from 1 domain to another and saving the data to a database, however i retrieve data from domain 1, but cant save to the database.

Here is the script from domain 1:

```
// Get Domain Name:
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// Get User IP Address:
$user = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

// Connect to Source:
$url = 'http://www.domain2.com/source.php';
    $fields = array(
                'id'=>'1',
                'user'=>$user,
        'domain'=>$domain,

            );

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = '?';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the script to save the data to the database on domain 2:

```
// Get domain and user details:
    $domain=$_GET['domain'];
    $user=$_GET['user'];

// Connection to MySQL Database.
    include ('_includes/_dbconnection.php');
    include ('_includes/_dbopen.php');

// Insert Data to MySQL Database
$sql="INSERT INTO traffic (url, cip)VALUES('$_POST[domain]', '$_POST[user]')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if($result){

    echo $domain;
    echo $user;

    }

    else {

    echo 'Not Input';
    }
```

Comment: just echo $sql on domain2 and echo $result on domain 1 to check how your sql looks like.

Comment: your insert id db data from $_POST, but doesn`t submit data. And you got data from curl in $result( doesnt use it). What your want to do ???

Comment: i receive data from domain 1, but for some reason dont want to save to the mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

You are posting the form with curl and trying to get the values with `$_GET`

Try to use `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`

```
$domain=$_POST['domain'];
$user=$_POST['user'];

// Connection to MySQL Database.
include ('_includes/_dbconnection.php');
include ('_includes/_dbopen.php');

// Insert Data to MySQL Database
$sql="INSERT INTO traffic (url, cip)VALUES('$domain', '$user')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
    echo $domain;
    echo $user;
}else {
    echo 'Not Input';
}
```

Comment: try setting *CURLOPT_POST*,  `curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1)` before `curl_exec($ch)`

Comment: try `$error = curl_error($curl);` and print the value $error and check  whether `$result` is TRUE